# HATEOAS Link using UriBuilder

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, hateoas

I have a REST service defined as below:

```
@Path("/v1/employee/")
EmployeeService {

@Path("/designation/")
public void listDesignation() {

}
}
```

My goal is to generate the relative URL "v1/employee/designation/".

If I use `UriBuilder.fromResource(EmployeeService.class)`,
it gives me "/v1/employee/"

And if i use `UriBuilder.fromMethod(EmployeeService.class, "listDesignation")`, it gives me "/designation"

Does anyone know how I can I get relative URL "v1/employee/designation" without doing any hard coding.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your `UriBuilder#fromResource(Class)`, then chain a call to `path(Class, String)` (class, method name) or `path(String)` (actual path) or `path(Method)` (actual method if you have it).